# Activity not changing from portrait mode to landscape mode in android

Tags: android

I am trying to change orientation from portrait to landscape for an Android activity. But it is not changing to landscape.

I mention the activity in the manifest file as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".OpenFileActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:exported="false">
```

But I am unsuccessful. Can any one tell me why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check in your phone's settings that screen rotation is enabled.

Comment: Thank you gabi,it worked for me,screen orientation was disabled in my phone :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen